# Changing text in Magento OPC page?

Tags: magento-1.9

How can i change text in checkout page and emails? Please see screenshot.[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the content in admin configuration itself.

Navigate to

> admin > system > configuration > payment methods > Bank Transfer Payment

And change the value in the `Instructions` field.[image: Image for system configuration]

Comment: I want to change the "instructions" text

Comment: Yes, you can change text and save it

Comment: I want to change what is highlighted in blue in your image and highlighted yellow in my image

Comment: send your admin screenshot

Comment: it is there in my question already.

Comment: You can change the text in admin panel.do you understand what I 'm trying to say?

Comment: How? Please explain. How can I change the text "Instructions"  to "Instructions to deposit"?

Comment: Your question was not to change the instruction. It's for instruction content.